# How to calculate from each row data textbox value in array?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I want to show total sum of values for each row data array. I have 5 rows of data, I want to get the results of each of data. Can anyone help me to figure it out?

```js
function subtotal(konversi){
    var hitung = (document.getElementById('quantity').value * document.getElementById('packing_value').value);
    document.forms.demoform.quantity_konversi.value = hitung; 
}
```

```html
<form id='demoform'>
<?php
$jumlah=5;
for($i=0; $i<$jumlah; $i++){
    $nomor = $i + 1;

    echo"$nomor";
?>

<input type='text' name='quantity[]' id='quantity' onchange="subtotal(this.value,getElementById('packing_value').value);">
X
<input type='text' id="packing_value" value='10' readonly='yes'>
<input type='text' name='quantity_konversi[]' id='quantity_konversi' placeholder='result ???'><br/>

<?php } $nomor++ ?>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that all the input fields have the same id. In HTML every element/html tag should have a unique id. So if you reference with the id JavaScript will find the first occurence of your id and use this element. All other elements are ignored even though they have the same id.
So remember ids are unique, classes can be used on several elements.

To solve your problem I added an unique ID at the end of the regular `quantity` id with the PHP variable `$nomor`:

```
<input type='text' name='quantity[]' id='quantity<?php echo"$nomor"; ?>' onkeyup="subtotal();">
```

The PHP server will make the following out of it:

```
<input type='text' name='quantity[]' id='quantity1' onkeyup="subtotal();">
<input type='text' name='quantity[]' id='quantity2' onkeyup="subtotal();">
    ...
<input type='text' name='quantity[]' id='quantity5' onkeyup="subtotal();">
```

You know have a unique id that can be referenced by JavaScript with the help of a running index inside of a for loop:

```
document.getElementById('quantity'+i).value
```

The same goes for `document.getElementById('packing_value'+i).value`

Finally the calculated value is saved in the correct field:

```
document.getElementById('quantity_konversi'+i).value = hitung;
```

FULL CODE (runnable at http://phpfiddle.org/):

```
<script>
        function subtotal(konversi){
            console.log('subtotal function');
            for(var i = 1; i < 5+1; i++){
                //console.log('quantity'+i, document.getElementById('quantity'+i).value);
                //console.log('packing_value'+i, document.getElementById('packing_value'+i).value);
                var hitung = (document.getElementById('quantity'+i).value * document.getElementById('packing_value'+i).value);
                //document.forms.demoform.quantity_konversi.value = hitung; 
                document.getElementById('quantity_konversi'+i).value = hitung; 
                console.log(i, hitung);
            }
        } 
    </script>
<form id='demoform'>
<?php
    $jumlah=5;
    for($i=0; $i<$jumlah; $i++){
        $nomor = $i + 1;    
        echo"$nomor";
?>

        <input type='text' name='quantity[]' id='quantity<?php echo"$nomor"; ?>' onkeyup="subtotal();">
        X
        <input type='text' id="packing_value<?php echo"$nomor"; ?>" value='10' onkeyup="subtotal();">

        <input type='text' name='quantity_konversi[]' id='quantity_konversi<?php echo"$nomor"; ?>' placeholder='result ???'><br/>
<?php

    } //for end 
    $nomor++ 
?>

</form>
```